# WordPress Installation Using Mamp: Error establishing a database connection

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mamp

I am a beginner in WordPress. I have been doing an Udemy course, entitled "WordPress Theme Development Using Bootstrap" by Brad Hussey.

I have installed MAMP. Then I followed all the instructions of the tutorial to create a new database and a new user account via PHPMyAdmin. Then I edit the wp-config-sample.php file appropriately using the correct credentials. I copied all the codes from https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ and paste them in the right place. Then I renamed the file to wp-config.php. Now, when I go to http://localhost/wp-admin/ in my browser, the following error appears:

```
Error establishing a database connection
This either means that the username and password information in your wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can't contact the database server at localhost. This could mean your host's database server is down.

Are you sure you have the correct username and password?
Are you sure that you have typed the correct hostname?
Are you sure that the database server is running?
If you're unsure what these terms mean you should probably contact your host. If you still need help you can always visit the WordPress Support Forums.
```

I have typed the correct username and password in the wp-config.php file. I had typed the hostname as "localhost". And MySQL server is running on MAMP. So, I have done everything correctly. But can't get rid of this frustrating issue. Please, help me. I cannot proceed further to this course without solving it.

I have already seen some of the YouTube videos explaining the same solution that I tried to follow. It worked for them, but not for me.